# Nest a user control inside another user control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, viewmodel

I have this scenario where I have a list view (user control) and a detail view (user control). When the user clicks an item in the list, the detail view will be shown with the corresponding data.

In my main window I am using Data Templates and Content Controllers to set the CurrentViewModel from selecting a menu item.

The data template

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:EquipmentListViewModel}">
            <equipment:EquipmentListView />
        </DataTemplate>
```

The menu item

```
<MenuItem Header="_List / Update" Command="{Binding NavCommand}" CommandParameter="equipList"></MenuItem>
```

The content control:

```
 <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}" />
```

Setting the current view model:

```
case "equipList":
                    CurrentViewModel = (EquipmentListViewModel)EquipmentListViewModel;
                    break;
```

When the user selects a list item an event is published:

```
_eventAggregator.GetEvent<OpenEquipmentDetailViewEvent>()
                        .Publish(_selectedEquipment.EquipmentId);
```

Which the detail view model then listens to:

```
 _eventAggregator.GetEvent<OpenEquipmentDetailViewEvent>()
                .Subscribe(OnOpenEquipmentDetailView);
```

The problem is that only one view model can be set as the current one at a time, while I need first the list view model to render the list and then the detail view model to render the details of the selected list item. I tried creating an instance of the detail view and using data context to bind the detail view model in the list view, but it did not bind the UI elements of the detail view to the properties in the view model.

The main view model for the main window creates instances of all the view models.

How can I correctly show the detail view, with the view model bound, when I select an item in my list?

Comment: You mean to create a "CurrentViewModel" property in my list view model to only display the detail user control? Edit: Thanks, I didn't see your edit.

Comment: Re-reading your question, I find that I actually have no idea what you're trying to do. If it's a simple master-detail relationship that would be trivial with MVVM, but if you need to find some way to get an event aggregator involved in that, I can't help you. I'd suggest changing your tags so you get some attention from folks who do that stuff. I'd tag whatever "MVVM" framework you're using.

Comment: Have you got a more complete sample of the problem?