# WPF Nested User Controls, expose lower controls properties

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

New to WPF, and it's obvious the advantages it gives you.

However, I'm struggling with nesting user controls and being able to access the nested controls properties from the top level, without duplication of code. This just seems wrong, and makes me feel I have missed something...

I have looked at other posts, this is the nearest [Nest a user control inside another user control in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47515859/nest-a-user-control-inside-another-user-control-in-wpf), but not specific enough and no answer

**Simple use case:**

I have created a "Number Only" TextBox, which (as the name suggests) only accepts characters [0-9.-]. But I also have created a property "Value" which can be used get/set the displayed value through a double. Then I have bound that property accordingly.

This NumberOnlyTextBox is then used in another user control, NumericUpDownControl... But I want to expose and bind the "Value" property of the NumberOnlyTextBox, without having to repeat the code behind for the NumericUpDownControl. Is it possible to do this within the XAML rather than re-write the properties and bindings?

**The code:**

NumberOnlyTextBox XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="PracticeWPF.UserControls.TextBoxNumberOnly"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PracticeWPF.UserControls"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="30" d:DesignWidth="120">
<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ValueString, Mode=OneWay}" PreviewTextInput="TextBox_PreviewTextInput" LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus"
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent"
             FontSize="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},Path=FontSize}"/>
</Grid>
```

NumberOnlyTextBox C#

```
public partial class TextBoxNumberOnly : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private static readonly Regex _regex = new Regex("[0-9.-]+");
    private double _value = 0;
    private string _valueString = "";
    private string _valueStringFormat = "#";

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    public double Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            _value = value;
            ValueString = _value.ToString(_valueStringFormat);
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value"));
        }
    }

    public string ValueStringFormat
    {
        get { return _valueStringFormat; }
        set
        {
            _valueStringFormat = value;
            ValueString = _value.ToString(_valueStringFormat);
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ValueStringFormat"));
        }
    }

    public string ValueString
    {
        get { return _valueString; }
        private set
        {
            _valueString = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ValueString"));
        }
    }

    public TextBoxNumberOnly()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void TextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = !IsTextAllowed(e.Text, _regex);
        if (((TextBox)sender).Text.Contains(".") && (e.Text == ".")) e.Handled = true;
    }

    private static bool IsTextAllowed(string text, Regex regex)
    {
        return regex.IsMatch(text);
    }

    private void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(((TextBox)sender).Text))
        {
            ((TextBox)sender).Text = "0";
        }
    }

}
```

Then the NumericUpDownControl XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="PracticeWPF.UserControls.IntegerUpDown"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PracticeWPF.UserControls"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="80" d:DesignWidth="120">
<Grid Background="Wheat">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <local:TextBoxNumberOnly x:Name="tbnoValueDisplay" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Name="UpButton" Grid.Row="0" Background="Green" Click="UpButton_Click"/>
        <Button Name="DownButton" Grid.Row="1" Background="Red" Click="DownButton_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Finally the NumericUpDownControl C#

```
public partial class IntegerUpDown : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double _value;
    private string _valueStringFormat = "#";
    private string _valueString = "";

    public double Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set { _value = value;
            ValueString = _value.ToString(_valueStringFormat);
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value"));
        }
    }

    public string ValueStringFormat
    {
        get { return _valueStringFormat; }
        set { _valueStringFormat = value;
            ValueString = _value.ToString(_valueStringFormat);
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ValueStringFormat"));
        }
    }
    public string ValueString
    {
        get { return _valueString; }
        private set
        {
            _valueString = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ValueString"));
        }
    }

    public IntegerUpDown()
    {
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    private void UpButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Value++;
    }

    private void DownButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Value--;
    }
}
```

**So the question is...**

1. Why am I repeating the properties of TextBoxNumberOnly in NumericUpDownControl?
2. Is there an easier way of writting this that avoids the code repition? Can I just expose the properties of TextBoxNumberOnly in the XAML of NumericUpDownControl?

My experience is telling me I'm doing something wrong, but I can't see how to solve it!
Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are these nested UserControls at all? TextBoxNumberOnly could be a derived TextBox, and IntegerUpDown could be a derived TextBoxNumberOnly. Additional visual elements like the up/down buttons would go into the ControlTemplate.

Comment: To be honest, I just wanted to create my own user control for TextBoxNumberOnly, and agree it should derive from TextBox. However, IntegerUpDown will need associated buttons, won't that lend itself to user control grouping this functionality together? But the question still remains, can you "pass through" properties so they can be bound further up?

Comment: You could declare attached properties with value inheritance, but that seems overkill.

Comment: A developer new to WPF, including myself, tends to rely on `UserControl` but gradually realizes that wiring up the properties of inner controls would be unbearably onerous...

Comment: @emoacht completely agree, as I'm starting to realise.

Comment: As Clemens already suggested, most requirements for visual elements could be solved by  ControlTemplate.

Comment: The number only functionality should be a behavior IMO. You then don't need a number only control at all. And your parent control for numeric updown can then be a usercontrol if you wanted. Or just a template. You don't even need to define custom or user controls for dependency properties. You can use attached dependency properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why am I repeating the properties of TextBoxNumberOnly in NumericUpDownControl?

Because the `NumericUpDownControl` "wraps" (or rather hides) the `TextBoxNumberOnly` control, i.e. the latter is an implementation detail of the former and there is no way to directly interact with the "hidden" `TextBoxNumberOnly` from the `NumericUpDownControl` unless you expose it somehow.

> Is there an easier way of writting this that avoids the code repition? Can I just expose the properties of TextBoxNumberOnly in the XAML of NumericUpDownControl?

No, not in the XAML. If you want to be able to set a property of the inner control by setting or binding a property of the outer control in the XAML markup, you should define "wrapper" dependency properties in the outer control class and then bind the inner control property to the outer control property, e.g.:

```
<local:InnerControl Name="UpButton"
                    Value="{Binding ValueOfOuter,
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" ... />
...
<local:OuterControl ValueOfOuter="{Binding ViewModelProperty}" ... />
```

Comment: I have marked this as correct because it has answered my questions. Not what I wanted to hear! Solving my problem has been done using the input from @Clemens - thanks all for helping me gain a little more understanding of WPF.